# Does the grafana production app_mode can not load unsigned plugins in data/plugins directory ？

Tags: grafana, grafana-plugin

**What happened**:
when I use development app_mode, the grafana can load my custom plugin success.
But when the app_mode is production, it can not load success.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frD8A.png)

**Environment**:

- Grafana version: v8.2.3
- Data source type & version: Custom datasource plugin、Custom panel plugin
- OS Grafana is installed on: Linux
- User OS & Browser: Chrome
- config： allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Grafana [default.ini](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/conf/defaults.ini) with comments or [doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#allow_loading_unsigned_plugins):

```
# Enter a comma-separated list of plugin identifiers to identify plugins to load even if they are unsigned. Plugins with modified signatures are never loaded.
allow_loading_unsigned_plugins =
```

So, `allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = true` is not correct configuration, but:

```
allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = my-plugin-1,my-plugin-2
```

is correct.